# Why CSS Descendant Combinator doesn't overrides styles of Class Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I've used example in the spec [Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) to determine selectors weight. Both selectors have specificity: 11 points. 
11 = 10 (class name) + 1 (element name)

According to specification [w3c cascading rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) the 2nd selector should override the 1st one because it appears later in the file. 
Therefore, my question is why the paragraph is still red?

```css
p.c11 {             
  color: darkred;
}

p .c11 {              
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <p class="c11">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, eius iusto     provident laudantium voluptates adipisci voluptatem amet repudiandae ex aspernatur rem voluptatibus recusandae vero corporis distinctio quia reprehenderit dolores facere.
    </p>
</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Therefore, my question is why the paragraph is still red?

Your HTML is invalid. You can't nest `p` elements. See the [relevant spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) for a list of elements that the `p` element can contain.

Since it's invalid, this is how the element(s) are being rendered:

```
<p class="c11">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
<p></p>
```

[image]

The paragraph is still red because the selector `p .c11` will select an element with a class of `c11` that is a descendant of a `p` element. The space in the selector `p .c11` is a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). Since you can't nest `p` elements, the selector `p .c11` isn't selecting anything.

Comment: Why I can nest div's but cannot do the same for 'p'?

Comment: @ieXcept Because a document division can contain smaller document divisions, but it makes no sense for a paragraph to contain other paragraphs.

Comment: Also, are you sure a `p` can't be nested in a `p`. According to the spec, `p` can exist within flow content, of which `p` is a part.

Comment: @Oriol, I understand it doesn't make sense, but I'm not sure it's invalid.

Comment: @Michael_B [`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) can only be used where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is expected, and the content model of `p` is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1). So you can't nest paragraphs.

Comment: @Michael_B What Oriol said. Also, it doesn't [validate](https://validator.w3.org/). The following error is thrown: *"No p element in scope but a p end tag seen."*